# User access to pages that admin assigns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, user-roles

I am working on ASP.Net MVC application where admin can assign access to individual user on different pages.

I applied user roles such as `Admin`, `supervisor` and `End-user` and `[authorize]` attribute. it is working fine but now **i want user to access such pages that admin assigns him**.

Currently trying to `override` `OnAuthorize()` method so that i can get the action name and check (from the DB) if the user have `access rights` or `redirect` it to another page (Stating: "You do not have permission")

**Note**: I saved all the rights of form like active, add, update, delete etc in DB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the built-in `AuthorizationAttribute`, override its `AuthorizeCore` methid and implement your logic in there. Like this:

```
public class UserBasedCustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        ... do your checking here
```

Here's the Microsoft implementation, that takes care of `Roles`:
[AuthorizeAttribute.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs)